# Merging three solutions in biztalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have three applications in Biztalk (with three different DLL 's)  which are all working fine.

For Ex:Solution A ,Solution B,Solution C.

I have to merge these three into single application ,generate a single DLL and deploy it.

Solution required:
Solution D with all functionality.

what can be possible methods to accomplish this ,if i don't have to build new project from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new solution and copy all the artifacts from solution a, b, and c to this one. As a best practice, you should not have all artifacts such as schemas, orchestrations, maps in one dll/project. They all should be in separate assemblies but can be in one solution.

Answer (score 0):

**My official Answer, don't bother.**  There is absolutely no reason to do this.

There are no benefits...and no real drawback either.

If someone it telling you to do this, find out why they think this and we can help you explain to them how this actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new BizTalk project in a separate solution. Then copy all the artifacts from the other three solutions into this new project. Compile, deploy and configure in a new BizTalk application.

However, in general, designing the structure of a solution is a task that requires deliberation and effort considering the requirements of your application.
There are various best practices,patterns and guidelines , for instance [here](https://blog.sierrasystems.com/2013/10/12/biztalk-integration-development-architecture/) and [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/johanlindfors/BizTalk-Server-Development-Best-Practices-12) , that will guide anyone in the right direction.